# haproxy http request <NOSRV> reponse

Tags: http, haproxy

I have following configuration in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

```
> frontend LB
>         bind *:80
>         reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
>         default_backend LB
> 
> frontend LBS
>         bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/xy.pem
>         reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
>         default_backend LB
> 
> backend LB *:80
>         redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
>         mode http
>         stats enable
>         stats hide-version
>         stats uri /stats
>         stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
>         stats auth xxxx:yyyyyy         
>         balance roundrobin                      
>         option httpchk
>         option  httpclose
>         option forwardfor
>         cookie LB insert
>         server web1-srv xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80 cookie web1-srv check         
>         server web2-srv xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80 cookie web2-srv check
```

From log i have impression that https requests are not working

[07/Aug/2018:12:35:01.402] LB LB/ 10/-1/-1/-1/10 302 121 - - LRNN 0/0/0/0/3 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"

Answer (score 1):

Your frontend LBS "offloads"  the https, and passes a http request to backend LB.  Which then redirects to https.  As you can see in your log:  302.

BTW, I think you should remove the "*:80" from your backend.  The frontend LB is bound to port 80.

Comment: you means i should chanage  backend LB *:80 to  backend LB *:443
my back end server are on 443

Comment: No, I said "remove", not "replace".  Don't bind the backend.  "backend LB *:80" becomes "backend LB".

Comment: thanks and 
server web1-srv xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80 should i change to 
server web1-srv xx.xx.xxx.xxx:443 
because website is configured to 443?

Comment: No, the frontend took away the SSL. So you talk HTTP to the origin servers.  ("mode http").

Comment: I removed following line  and there is no more <NOSRV> in log
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

Comment: What took you so long?   Everything OK now?